# trying to return value from python file to c# using IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

i am using a c# windows forum and running a python file using iron python, the file is running but i would like to be able to use the output on c#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"hi_test.py");
     }
```

python

```
print("hi")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IronPython w/ C# - How to Read Values of Python Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825597/ironpython-w-c-sharp-how-to-read-values-of-python-variables)